# Using glLoadMatrixd on specific vertices?

Tags: c, opengl, matrix

I am trying to do skeletal animation in legacy OpenGL and thought I could use matrices on individual vertices. When I programmed it and it didn't work, I did some Googling to find this: https://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/glLoadMatrix.html

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glLoadMatrix is executed between the execution of glBegin and the corresponding execution of glEnd.

So now I'm stumped. Here is a diagram:

[image]

Bones are labeled in red. I'm trying to do skeletal animation so there are two rectangles. One uses Bone 0 and the second uses Bone 1. Only specific vertices of the triangles that make the second rectangle use the rotation matrix of Bone 1, and the ones that don't use the rotation matrix of Bone 0, kind of making a snake, if that makes sense.

Since I cannot use glLoadMatrix for individual vertices in a triangle, what other way can I displace a vertex based on a stored matrix? Perhaps multiply some of the matrix values to the vertex? Not sure how to go about doing that. Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mention the two rectangles Bone0 and Bone1. You need to draw them separately since they need to have separate transformation matrices. Two points of the two rectangles are coincident, your transformation matrix to draw Bone1 must ensure that:

```
glTranslateF(...);
glRotateF(...);       /* position rectangle Bone0 */

glBegin(GL_QUADS);    /* draw rectangle Bone0 */
glVertex3f(...);      /* draw it */
    ... 
glEnd();

glPushMatrix();       /* save transformation matrix */

glMulMatrix(...);     /*
                       * as per your drawing, this is not just a
                       * simple translate/rotate operation, but
                       * a translate/shear
                       * you need to do that manually
                       */

glBegin(GL_QUADS);    /*
                       * draw rectangle Bone1. Two of the vertices are
                       * coincident with two of rectangle Bone0. Your
                       * shear matrix must ensure they are
                       */
glVertex3F(...);
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called skinning! And unfortunately it will involve a bit more effort than your approach. It is possible to do it between one begin and end, which is generally preferable.

The easiest way is not to use OpenGL to transform your vertices. Use your favourite matrix math library to multiply the vertices with your bone matrices before they get passed to OpenGL. If the number of vertices is not too large, it won't slow you down much.

The harder way is to implement a skinning shader. This [book chapter](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001814/ch09.html#ch09_id35816677) provides a good introduction on how that is done. The principle is to upload multiple matrices to OpenGL, and give each vertex an index which says which matrix to multiply with. This will be much faster than the easy approach.

GPUs are fast because they are optimized for doing the *same* operation on a large set of data - the tradeoff for this is that you can't modify the state (such as changing the matrix) while a draw call is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Heh, have been doing a lot of math stuff since I posted my question and checked back just now to post an answer for anyone with the same question, and I noticed I already have some answers, so thanks for answering with your input!

Since I have figured out a solution, though, I thought I would post an answer along with these other two.

Basically, what I am doing with the rendering is per-vertex rendering anyway, where it reads the vertices of each triangle from a data buffer and all of that, so it wasn't too much trouble to go ahead and write a custom function to multiply a matrix to a vertex, so a copy of the vertex is loaded from the buffer, the matrix is multiplied to it based on which bone the vertex is mapped to, and then that is used for rendering that particular vertex on the triangle.

Funny that I already had implemented what @Hannesh suggested and I just had to write the multiplier function. Very cool!

> The harder way is to implement a skinning shader. This book chapter provides a good introduction on how that is done. The principle is to upload multiple matrices to OpenGL, and give each vertex an index which says which matrix to multiply with. This will be much faster than the easy approach.

Thanks again! I'll up-vote whenever I have the reputation to do so!